# A Question about Cubic and Galois Fields

Tags: galois-theory, cubics

Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]: f(x) = x^3 + p x + q, p \geq 0, f$ irreducible therein; $\mathbb{k}$ be the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$; $G = Gal(\mathbb{k} / \mathbb{Q})$.  I have to show that $G \cong S_3$.
I have to prove it algebraically and using information from the pictoral graph of $f$.

I have already proven some results.  I have shown that $\exists!$ field $\mathbb{E}: \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{E} \subseteq \mathbb{k}, [\mathbb{E}:\mathbb{Q}]=2, \mathbb{E}=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})=\mathbb{k}^H$, where $D = -4p^3-27q^2$ and $H \leq G: H \cong A_3$. I also proved that $A_3 \cong H = G \implies \sqrt{D} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: The splitting field contains a root of $f(x)$, so it contains a field of degree 3 over the rationals; you have already shown it contains a quadratic field. This should suffice to complete the argument.

Comment: But why does that rely on $p \geq 0$? Without that condition, and even generalizing from $\mathbb{Q}$ to any field $\mathbb{F}$, I think that we only have $G \cong G' \in \left\{ {A_3, S_3}\right\}$.  The condition on $p$ must be the reason for the restriction of the possibilities to $G \cong G' \in \left\{ {S_3}\right\}$, right? And, regardless, how?

Comment: $p\ge0$ isn't a necessary condition, but it's clearly sufficient for $D$ to be negative and hence not a perfect square.

Comment: As $q$ appears in squared form its sign will not affect the discriminant's sign; also note that by choosing a polynomial with coefficient of $x^3$ as $+1$, in some sense we are in a special case. Try to solve the same problem for the polynomial $-x^3+px+q$